# jQuery loading old data

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have a little problem with jQuery.get function. I am loading 2 files from backend.

```
jQuery.get('../db/analog_vstup_11A.txt',function(data_analog){
   jQuery.get('../db/analog_vstup_11C.txt',function(data_analog118){
    console.log(data_analog118);
    *** some logic ***
  });
});
```

I am trying to print content of second file (analog_vstup_11C.txt) to console. It is working fine, but if I change some value in the file, it dont change in console. I dont know why. If I delete the file, I dont get error and console still shows content of detelted file. If I rename analog_vstup_11C.txt to some another it works fine. Where could be mistake? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default jquery ajax call result are cached. You can remove the old cache by adding a param to [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) call by using [`jQuery.now()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) like:

```
jQuery.get('../db/analog_vstup_11A.txt', { "_": jQuery.now() }, function(data_analog){
   jQuery.get('../db/analog_vstup_11C.txt', { "_": jQuery.now() }, function(data_analog118){
    console.log(data_analog118);
    *** some logic ***
  });
});
```